# Handling response when hit any URL

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program in which I want, when I hit any url or u can say websites, all contents of that websites is being read by me. I am using URL class for this.

Here is my code ..

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;
 public class URLConnectionReader 
 {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
     URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/index.html");
     URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)

    System.out.println(inputLine);

    in.close();
}
}
```

But In response it is showing view page source's contents, I want only web-page contents, not all. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Then parse that HTML you recieved using HTML parser (like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org))

Answer (score 0):

web-page contents == page source. the browser analyze the html and visualize it for human eye.
if you want only the body text you can use jsoup:

```
String text = Jsoup.parse(html).body().text();
```

but you gonna get also some commercials, menus and other text that not necessary the content you wanted.